# unable to cover below lines in my test class

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

i am unable to cover this lines in my test class can any one give me some idea how to do this.

```
    public Integer compareTo(Object compareTo) {

        WRNWrapper compareToWr = (WRNWrapper)compareTo;

        Integer returnValue = 0;

        if (getDate(this.openedDate) > getDate(compareToWr.openedDate)) {
            returnValue = -1;
        } else if (getDate(this.openedDate) < getDate(compareToWr.openedDate)) {
            returnValue = 1;
        }

        return returnValue;       
       }

       private DateTime getDate(String dt) {

        String[] dt2 = dt.split(' ');
        String[] dtFields = dt2[0].split('/');
        String[] tmFields = dt2[1].split(':');
        return system.Datetime.newInstance(Integer.valueOf(dtFields[2]), Integer.valueOf(dtFields[0]), Integer.valueOf(dtFields[1]), 
                                            Integer.valueOf(tmFields[0]), Integer.valueOf(tmFields[1]), Integer.valueOf(tmFields[2]));
        }
     }
   }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE, @milan. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create instances of `WRNWrapper` and call the `compareTo` method asserting the outcomes:

```
@isTest
static void compareTo() {

    // Construct some example objects
    WRNWrapper w1 = new WRNWrapper(...);
    WRNWrapper w2 = new WRNWrapper(...);
    WRNWrapper w3 = new WRNWrapper(...);

    // Assuming w1 is created so it should sort earlier than w2
    System.assertEquals(-1, w1.compareTo(w2));
    System.assertEquals(1, w2.compareTo(w1));

    // Assuming w3 is created so it short sort exactly the same as w2
    System.assertEquals(0, w2.compareTo(w3));
    System.assertEquals(0, w3.compareTo(w2));
}
```

Comment: @milan You didn't supply the source code of that class so I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

This is a function from the Comparable interface. I suppose you implemented it to allow sorting a list of WRNWrapper objects.
So create "list", add objects to it and sort it. This way you can also make sure the sort works as expected (descending/ascending is often not intuitive)

Comment: @milan you answer was cut off...